# Error propagation, why use variences?

Tags: probability, error-propagation

I have been reading up on error propagation and am slightly confused about something.

We can the error in $c=f(a,b)$ as the:
$$\sigma(c)= f_a \sigma_a+f_b \sigma _b$$
Firstly is this correct and am I correct in saying that the partial derivatives are evaluated at the mean of $a$ and $b$?

Ever where I look, however, they do not seem to quote this formula but rather square it and assume that $a$ and $b$ are indepdent we get:

$$\sigma(c)^2= f_a^2 \sigma_a^2+f_b^2 \sigma _b^2$$
What is the advantage of this expression over  my first one since it seems less accurate due to us having to assume independence, which is not necessary with my first formula.

Comment: The first is worst case and the second assumes the errors are independent and gives a slightly less conservative error estimate.

Comment: The formulas are based on the linearity hypothesis, so that $f_a$ and $f_b$ should be constant and where you evaluate them shouldn't matter. Indeed in practice you will use the mean. It can be a good sanity check to evaluate the derivatives at the extreme values and compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume that you measure $a$ and $b$ with error that has a standard deviation of $\sigma_a,\sigma_b$, respectively. We can model your  measurements as $\hat a = a+\epsilon_a,\hat b = b+\epsilon_b$, where $Var(\epsilon_a)=\sigma_a^2,Var(\epsilon_b)=\sigma_b^2$ and $E[\epsilon_a]=E[\epsilon_b]=0$.

Then, we can write $\hat c = f(\hat a, \hat b)$.

Now, here's the **big assumption** in all of error propagation: $\frac{\sigma_a}{\mu_a}, \frac{\sigma_b}{\mu_b}\ \ll 1$..this justifies our ability to use the *linearization* of $f(a,b)$ (i.e., $L[f(a,b)]$) to estimate the measurement error of $c$:

$ L[f(x+\Delta a,y+\Delta b)]_{a,b}=f(a,b) + f_x|_a \times(\Delta a) + f_y|_b \times (\Delta b)$

Given small enough perturbations ($\Delta$), we can say that $f(a+\Delta a,b+\Delta b) \approx L[f(x+\Delta a,y+\Delta b)]_{a,b}$ if $|\Delta a|, |\Delta b|\ll 1$

Now, lets replace $a+\Delta a$ with $a+\epsilon_a$ and similarly for $b$ and see where this leads us:

$\hat c = f(a+\epsilon_a,b+\epsilon_b) \approx f(a,b)+f_x|_a \times(\epsilon_a) + f_y|_b \times (\epsilon_b)$

We can clean this up by letting $f_a:=f_x|_a$ and $f_b:=f_y|_b$:

$\hat c \approx f(a,b)+ f_a\epsilon_a + f_b\epsilon_b$

Thus, we've turned $\hat c$ into a random variable:

$E[\hat c]= f(a,b), \;\; Var[\hat c] = (f_a)^2\sigma^2_a + (f_b)^2\sigma^2_b + 2 f_af_b\sigma_{ab}$

If the errors are independent, then the last term is $0$ and we get:

$\sigma^2_{\hat c}=(f_a)^2\sigma^2_a + (f_b)^2\sigma^2_b$, which is your second equation.

Now, if we don't assume independence, we can use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Probability_theory), which in a probabilistic context states:

$$(\sigma_{XY})^2\leq \sigma^2_X \sigma^2_Y$$

Therefore, to maximize the value of $\sigma_{\hat c}^2$, we should set $\sigma_{ab}=\sigma_{a}\sigma_{b}$, which gives us:

$\sigma^2_{\hat c}=(f_a)^2\sigma^2_a + (f_b)^2\sigma^2_b + 2 f_af_b\sigma_{a}\sigma_{b}=(f_a\sigma_{a}+f_b\sigma_{b})^2\implies \sigma_{\hat c}=f_a\sigma_{a}+f_b\sigma_{b}$, which is your first equation.

So, as copper.hat said, the second equation in your post assumes independent errors, and hence does not maximize the variability. The first equation in your post is an *upper bound* on the error, since it assumes they are perfectly correlated, so the errors are always in the same direction as each other and proportional in magnitude.

To recap, propagation of error equations rely on the *smallness* of the error relative to the measurement (i.e., small signal to noise ratio) to allow for simplifying lineralizations to be used. Then, depending on how correlated you feel the errors are, you can adjust the variability appropriately using the covariance explicitly, or relying on an assumption of independence or perfect positive correlation.

Comment: Relating this to total diffentials and using these to error estimate, are we then saying that $\Delta f \approx. f_a \Delta x + f_b \Delta y$ gives the worst case, given if one of $\Delta x$ or $\Delta y <0$ and the other $>0$?? Also when we write this in terms of infinitesimal values i.e. $df= f_a dx + f_b dy$ does this allows hold, no matter the correlation between the variables?

Comment: @Joseph sorry, I didn't really understand your comment. But I think the answer is yes. If x and y are perfectly **positively** correlated, then your error propagation formula reduces to a total differential. Your differential formulation makes sense from a deterministic viewpoint, but it will not translate to a probabilistic context without some machinery from stochastic differential equations.